# DLookup Multiple Criteria Runtime Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to create a DLookup with multiple criteria in Access 2010, and running into a little trouble. I create invoices via a form. On the invoice form I select the AccountID, and set billing month and year. Based on that information, I would like to search my Prepayment query (quePrepayment) and pull in any prepayments that match those three criteria.

I am currently getting this error:

Run-time error '3075':
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'AccountID= & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID & Billing_Month = & Forms![frmInvoices]!Billing_Month & Billing_Year = & Forms![frmInvoices]!Billing_Year)'

```
Private Sub AccountID_Change()
Billing_Prepayment = DLookup("Total_Prepayment", "quePrepayment", "[AccountID] = & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID And [Billing_Month] = & Forms![frmInvoices]!Billing_Month And [Billing_Year] = & Forms![frmInvoices]!Billing_Year")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the third `DLookup` argument a string with the `Forms![frmInvoices]` control references built into it.  (The db engine can de-reference those controls when it evaluates the expression.)

```vb
Billing_Prepayment = DLookup("Total_Prepayment", "quePrepayment", _
    "[AccountID] = Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID And [Billing_Month] = Forms![frmInvoices]!Billing_Month And [Billing_Year] = Forms![frmInvoices]!Billing_Year")
```

However, that string is so long it may be challenging to see whether it is built correctly.  You can use an approach like this instead ...

```vb
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "[AccountID] = Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID " & _
    "And [Billing_Month] = Forms![frmInvoices]!Billing_Month " & _
    "And [Billing_Year] = Forms![frmInvoices]!Billing_Year")
Debug.Print strCriteria
Billing_Prepayment = DLookup("Total_Prepayment", "quePrepayment", _
    strCriteria)
```

Then in case of trouble, you can go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) to examine what was built for *strCriteria*.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was able to get it working, and see what I was doing wrong.  Thanks for the help!